# How to assign NULL to structure member

Tags: c

Here is the code

```
struct stack {
    int item;
    struct stack *next=NULL;
};
```

I want to make the pointer initially point to null but this shows error

> error:expected ':' , ',' , ';' , '}' or '*attribute*' before'=' token

Comment: it's because you cannot do that in C. You can do that from C++ 11 (it's not even C). Maybe you need to switch to C++ to be able to use default constructors.

Comment: Remember, C doesn't have constructors. When exactly would you expect this initialisation to take place?

Comment: Good book is needed.

Comment: At the point of definition of a variable of that type. `struct stack pile = { 0, NULL };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fragment posted does not define an object, it defines a type.

In C you cannot specify the default value of a member in a type definition. You can specify the values of members in an initializer:

```
struct stack {
    int item;
    struct stack *next;
};

struct stack my_stack = { 0, NULL };
```

If you omit the last member in the initializer, it will be initialized to the zero of its type, `NULL` for a pointer:

```
struct stack my_stack = { 0 };  // my_stack.next is NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

One creates a variable of that type, then puts initialization values in braces.

```
struct stack 
{
    int item;
    struct stack *next;

} stackVar = { 0, NULL};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform initializations inside of a struct definition. You can initialize a stack as such:

```
struct stack {
    int item;
    struct stack* next;
};

int main(){
    struct stack s = {0,NULL};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ask your struct type to set that pointer to null by itself. You will have to do it explicitly every time you create an object of type `struct stack`, e.g.

```
struct stack my_stack = { .next = NULL };
```

or

```
struct stack my_stack = { 0 };
```

Both variants have the same effect - they set to zero all fields of `my_stack`.

If you create your `struct stack` objects in dynamic memory, then initialization syntax is out of question. You will have to explicitly *assign* the initial value to your freshly created object, e.g.

```
struct stack *my_stack = malloc(sizeof *my_stack);
my_stack->next = NULL;
```

or

```
struct stack *my_stack = malloc(sizeof *my_stack);
*my_stack = (struct stack) { 0 };
// or 
*my_stack = (struct stack) { .next = NULL };
```

Comment: There is a subtile difference between the 2 alternatives presented last: `my_stack->item` is uninitialized in the first case.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, I specifically tried to match what appeared to be the OP's intent: to initialize only `next`. In that sense this version is the only one that provides the exact match, while the other ones are formally "excessive".

Comment: that is a good point, but given the OP's skill level, I doubt he meant anything so precise.